# Memory leak GetNamedSecurityInfoW

Tags: python, winapi, ctypes, pywin32

I'm trying to get file owner information (domain and user name) with ctypes. In python to get files list I used os.walk.

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk("c:\\"):
    for file in files:
    filename = os.path.join(root, file)
    owner = PL_Files.get_fileowner(filename)
    print(owner)
```

to get owner information in 'PL_Files.get_fileowner', I'm using GetNamedSecurityInfoW. It's works well (it returns domain and user name).

```
@staticmethod
def get_fileowner(filename):
    dwRet = 0
    pSidOwner = c_void_p()
    ppSecurityDescriptor = c_void_p()
    dwAcctName = DWORD()
    dwDomainName = DWORD()
    peUse = DWORD(SidTypeUnknown)
        
    dwRet = GetNamedSecurityInfoW(filename, SE_FILE_OBJECT, OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION, byref(pSidOwner), None, None, None, None)
        if dwRet != ERROR_SUCCESS:
            return "-1"

        LookupAccountSidW(None, pSidOwner, None, byref(dwAcctName), None, byref(dwDomainName), byref(peUse))
        
        AcctName = create_unicode_buffer(dwAcctName.value + 2)
        DomainName = create_unicode_buffer(dwDomainName.value + 2)
        
        if LookupAccountSidW(None, pSidOwner, AcctName, byref(dwAcctName), DomainName, byref(dwDomainName), byref(peUse)):
            return "{}\{}".format(DomainName.value, AcctName.value)
        else:
            return "-1"
```

The issue is that every every calls to PL_Files.get_fileowner(filename) my process memory increasing with about 2MB.

Same result when I commented (didn't call) LookupAccountSidW function. So I think I have a problem with GetNamedSecurityInfoW function. GetNamedSecurityInfoW doesn't need freeing memory (if you don't use ppSecurityDescriptor).

Function prototype:

```
GetNamedSecurityInfoW = ADVAPI32.GetNamedSecurityInfoW
GetNamedSecurityInfoW.restype = DWORD
GetNamedSecurityInfoW.argtypes = [c_wchar_p, INT, DWORD, c_void_p, c_void_p, c_void_p, c_void_p, c_void_p]
```

Comment: You are required to provide `ppSecurityDescriptor`, which you must then free. Seems odd the API would succeed as is since it goes against the documentation.

Comment: @Luke Omg, problem solved. Thank you very much. It's my misstake - MSDN said: This parameter is required if any one of the ppsidOwner, ppsidGroup, ppDacl, or ppSacl parameters is not NULL.

Comment: Don't forget to `LocalFree` the security descriptor once done with `pSidOwner`.  The optional pointers reference that descriptor.  This is also mentioned in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/aclapi/nf-aclapi-getnamedsecurityinfow#parameters)

Answer (score 0):

When working with *CTypes* one needs to pay attention to:

1. [[SO]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58611011/4788546) for a common pitfall
2. The documentation of every function (and do what instructed there)

But for this case, worth mentioning [[GitHub]: mhammond/pywin32 - Python for Windows (pywin32) Extensions](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32) which is a *Python* wrapper over *WinAPI*s. Documentation (*WiP*) can be found at [[GitHub.MHammond]: Python for Win32 Extensions Help](https://mhammond.github.io/pywin32) (or [[ME.TimGolden]: Python for Win32 Extensions Help](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/contents.html)), since **question was also tagged** for it.
Here's an alternative implementation making use of it.

*code00.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import sys

import pywintypes as pwts
import win32security as wsec


def fileowner_pywin32(file_name):
    try:
        sec_desc = wsec.GetNamedSecurityInfo(file_name, wsec.SE_FILE_OBJECT, wsec.OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION)
    except pwts.error as e:
        #print(e)
        return None
    else:
        owner_sid = sec_desc.GetSecurityDescriptorOwner()
        #print(owner_sid)
        try:
            name, domain, _ = wsec.LookupAccountSid(None, owner_sid)
        except pwts.error as e:
            #print(e)
            return None
        else:
            return f"{domain}\\{name}"


def main(*argv):
    test_dir = argv[0] if argv else os.getcwd()
    max_files = int(argv[1]) if len(argv) >= 2 and argv[1].isdigit() else 10
    print(f"Display file (max: {max_files}) information for: {test_dir}")
    total_files = 0
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(test_dir):
        for file in files:
            #print(root, file)
            file_full = os.path.join(root, file)
            owner = fileowner_pywin32(file_full)
            print(f"{file_full}: {owner}")
            total_files += 1
            if max_files > 0 and total_files >= max_files:
                return


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Python {:s} {:03d}bit on {:s}\n".format(" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")),
                                                   64 if sys.maxsize > 0x100000000 else 32, sys.platform))
    rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
    print("\nDone.\n")
    sys.exit(rc)
```

**Output**:

> ```
> [cfati@CFATI-W10PC064:e:\Work\Dev\StackExchange\StackOverflow\q077878192]> "c:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.10_test0\Scripts\python.exe" ./code00.py "c:" 20
> Python 3.10.10 (tags/v3.10.10:aad5f6a, Feb  7 2023, 17:20:36) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] 064bit on win32
>
> Display file (max: 20) information for: c:
> c:DumpStack.log: BUILTIN\Administrators
> c:DumpStack.log.tmp: None
> c:pagefile.sys: None
> c:swapfile.sys: None
> c:$GetCurrent\Logs\downlevel_2021_05_15_23_18_17_211.log: BUILTIN\Administrators
> c:$GetCurrent\Logs\oobe_2021_05_16_04_23_10_420.log: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
> c:$GetCurrent\Logs\PartnerSetupCompleteResult.log: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
> c:$GetCurrent\SafeOS\GetCurrentOOBE.dll: BUILTIN\Administrators
> c:$GetCurrent\SafeOS\GetCurrentRollback.ini: BUILTIN\Administrators
> c:$GetCurrent\SafeOS\PartnerSetupComplete.cmd: BUILTIN\Administrators
> c:$GetCurrent\SafeOS\preoobe.cmd: BUILTIN\Administrators
> c:$GetCurrent\SafeOS\SetupComplete.cmd: BUILTIN\Administrators
> c:$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-18\desktop.ini: BUILTIN\Administrators
> c:$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-21-2542118664-3911450730-4233525012-1000\desktop.ini: None
> c:$Recycle.Bin\S-1-5-21-2542118664-3911450730-4233525012-1001\desktop.ini: CFATI-W10PC064\cfati
> c:Download\EnergyPlus-22.2.0-c249759bad-Windows-i386.zip: BUILTIN\Administrators
> c:Download\strawberry-perl-5.32.1.1-64bit.msi: BUILTIN\Administrators
> c:Install\MS\SysInternalsSuite\Version\accesschk.exe: BUILTIN\Administrators
> c:Install\MS\SysInternalsSuite\Version\accesschk64.exe: BUILTIN\Administrators
> c:Install\MS\SysInternalsSuite\Version\AccessEnum.exe: BUILTIN\Administrators
>
> Done.
> ```